# Convert Google mail folders to English

Tags: php, imap, gdata, gmail-imap

I am working on to backup a Google mails . I have stuck at when retrieve a other language folders.
Google return some encoded string while retrieve a folder (If only the account not in English ).
I need to take All Mail,Starred , Important labels for my purpose . How to retrieve that or how to decode this and find the respective English word for that.

Google Returned String : `[Gmail]/&C44LsgvNC7ILvg- &C4ULngvNC5oLsgvBC64LzQ-`
Excepted Output  : `[Gmail]/All Mail`

I am using Zend Gdata mail library for communicate with gmail

Comment: Please add the code you're using to get that output _to the question_.

Comment: Well, there's a couple things you can do: You can apply UTF-7 decoding (as defined in RFC 3501, and probably implemented in your library) to get the native language names back.  You can also use the List Extensions, and detect the \All, \Sent, \Trash, \Drafts, etc. flags, and then use the English names for them if you like.

Comment: Thankyou @Max i found an answer by using XLIST command .it will return english names for default labels (gmail default folders )

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [RFC 6154 (IMAP LIST Extension for Special-Use Mailboxes)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154) for that.

As described at the [Gmail APIs page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command), in the `LIST` response the "All Mail" folder should have an `\All` attribute, like this:

```
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \All) "/" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
```

That should be independent of the language used.